# How to loop save array of objects to mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I want to store this data to mongodb, But I don't know how to loop it, Tried for a long time and couldn't get the correct answer

There is tree data

```
[
  {
     name: 'A',
     children: [
       { 
         name: 'A1',
         children: [
           {
             name: 'A11',
             children: []
           }
         ]
       },
       {
         name: 'A2',
         children: []
       },
     ]
  },
  {
     name: 'B',
     children: [
       { 
          name: 'B1',
          children: []
       },
       { 
          name: 'B2',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'B21',
              children: []
            }
          ]
       },
     ]
  },
]
```

There is my Schema

```
const TempSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  parent: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Temp' },
}
```

I hope to get this result

```
{ _id: 5dea0671855f5d4b44774afd, name: 'A', parent: null, },
{ _id: 5dea07383ef7973e80883efd, name: 'A1', parent: 5dea0671855f5d4b44774afd, },
{ _id: 5dea07461047036d7c958771, name: 'A11', parent: 5dea07383ef7973e80883efd, },
{ _id: 5def00c05de2b22f8e6b9bfe, name: 'A2', parent: 5dea0671855f5d4b44774afd, },
...
```

This problem has troubled me for a long time, hope to get everyone's help, thank you!

Comment: Documentation on how to [Model Tree Structures](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/applications/data-models-tree-structures/).

Comment: Thank you @prasad_ , Now the question is how to save that tree to mongodb, How to loop insert ?

Comment: There are various ways to insert documents into MongoDB database collections. Here are some: [insertMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/index.html) and [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/index.html). You can run `mongoimport` from the operating system command prompt and the `insertMany` (or its variants) form _mongo shell_. I am assuming the documents are in JSON format, which will be input to the above commands.

Comment: Thank you @prasad_ ! I think it should be saved one by one, but I don't know how to do it. In a nutshell, flatten an array of objects into mongodb

Comment: You can insert using any of the methods, they basically insert / save one after another. So, its a convenience to use different methods:`insertOne()` or `insertMany()`. `insertMany` as such takes an array of documents as input and inserts one at a time, all the objects in the array: [MongoDB insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/tutorial/insert-documents/index.html). Another way is to insert/save the documents thru the code from a programming language, like C#, Java or JaavScript - there are associated driver softwares to use them with MongoDB.

Comment: Oh, @prasad_ My Good Friend, You still can't understand what I mean, I want the inserted document to retain the parent-child relationship through "parent" filed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create ID and flat

```
  const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
  const flatten = (data, parent = null) =>
    data.flatMap(e => {
      e._id = ObjectId();
      return ([{
        _id: e._id,
        parent,
        name: e.name
      },
      ...flatten(e.children, e._id)])
    });
  const result = flatten(tree);

  await Model.insertMany(result)
```